# $_GET not working with &amp; in the URL

Tags: php

Im working on a Wix widget. The iframe containing my widget has this URL generated by Wix:

> http://domain.com/wix/widget/?cacheKiller=123456&compId=hyeddksh&deviceType=desktop&instance=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&locale=en&viewMode=editor&width=50

I tried retriving the instance and compId values from the URL using $_GET but no luck.

```
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';
```

gives me

```
Array
(
    [cacheKiller] => 123456
    [amp;compId] => hyeddksh
    [amp;deviceType] => desktop
    [amp;instance] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [amp;locale] => en
    [amp;viewMode] => editor
    [amp;width] => 50
)
```

Any idea about retrieving these values without using **$_GET[amp;compId]** and **$_GET[amp;instance]**?

**EDIT**
To solve my issue, I am using `$compId = isset($_GET['compId']) ? $_GET['compId'] : $_GET['amp;compId'];`which I believe is not the right way. Anyone?

Comment: Anything wrong with `$_GET['compId']` ?

Comment: $_GET['compId'] is not define

Comment: Well, for some reason the & is getting escaped into the html entity name, I assume by Wix. Why do you escape it to the html entity name? Why not just have `&` instead of `&amp;` ?

Comment: Anyone, based on your edit `$compId = isset($_GET['compId']) ? $_GET['compId'] : isset($_GET['amp;compId']) ? $_GET['amp;compId']: null;` would work fine, and give a null value, rather than a warning, if neither is set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a ***mega quick and dirty hack***, you could use [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/array_walk).

```
array_walk($_GET, function($value, $key) use(&$_GET) {
     $_GET[str_replace('amp;', '', $key)] = $_GET[$key];
     unset($_GET[$key]);
});
```

[<kbd>**See it in action**</kbd>](https://eval.in/204055)

Then you can use the keys without the `amp;` prefix.